# Phase shift between coherent longitudinal waves facing each other

Tags: waves, coherence

In the following problem:

2 speakers are 6 feets away from each other and facing each other, assuming that they are 2 coherent sources of sound waves (so longitudinal waves), what is the phase shift between the waves at a point on the axes between the speakers?

I am told that it is: $\Delta\phi= k(6-x) - kx$

What I don't get is why isn't there a time depend term with opposite signs since the sources are facing each other ? Which would give: $\Delta\phi= k(6-x) + \omega t - (kx - \omega t) = k(6-x) - kx + 2 \omega t$ , so with phase shift changing with time (which kind of make sense to me when I try to picture waves moving toward each others).

EDIT: It is the question of an old exam from which I have the solution of the teacher that I don't understand. I'm trying to understand a concept for my coming exam here... (other student I asked the question to are also confused..  so this would actually really help). I understand your policy though and I'm going to reformulate a new post with a very general question about the underlying concept only.